# TF Lite C API crashes on second iteration

Tags: c, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use the C API of TF Lite to execute the inference cyclically, e.g. I set up the interpreter and feed him inputs every second or so to get predictions.

For this purpose, I have built `libtensorflowlite_c.so` via bazel. As documented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h), I try to do the inference like this, but inside a for loop to simulate the cyclic execution:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Iteration: %d\n", i);

        float input[49] = { 0.0 };
        TfLiteModel* model = TfLiteModelCreateFromFile("model.tflite");
        TfLiteInterpreterOptions* options = TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate();
        TfLiteInterpreterOptionsSetNumThreads(options, 2);
        TfLiteInterpreter* interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, options);
        TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(interpreter);

        TfLiteTensor* input_tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, 0);
        TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(input_tensor, input, 49 * sizeof(float));

        TfLiteInterpreterInvoke(interpreter);

        const TfLiteTensor* output_tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 14);

        float output[49];
        TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(output_tensor, output, 49 * sizeof(float));

        printf("Output: \n\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 49; j++) {
            printf("%d: %f\n", j, output[j]);
        }

        TfLiteInterpreterDelete(interpreter);
        TfLiteInterpreterOptionsDelete(options);
        TfLiteModelDelete(model);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first iteration runs fine and returns something. But on the second iteration, I get a SegFault when calling `TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(output_tensor, output, 49 * sizeof(float));`. Reason for this is that the previous function `TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor` returns a nullpointer.

I expected to run this multiple times without any problems, as I destroy all old instances of variables at the end of the for-loop and thus start a fresh interpreter everytime. Obviously, this is not the case.

Can somebody provide any guidance on this? Also, I know that I probably do not have to create an interpreter on every iteration, but I wanted to make sure that everything is created new when I start over again.

EDIT:

I tried rewriting the code to exclude unnecessary parts from the actual loop:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    float input[49] = {0.0};
    float output[49] = {[0 ... 48] = 2.5};

    TfLiteModel* model = TfLiteModelCreateFromFile("VariationalAutoencoder_440.tflite");
    TfLiteInterpreterOptions* options = TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate();
    TfLiteInterpreterOptionsSetNumThreads(options, 2);
    TfLiteInterpreter* interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, options);
    TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(interpreter);
    TfLiteTensor* input_tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, 0);
    const TfLiteTensor* output_tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 14);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nIteration: %d\n", i);
        TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(input_tensor, input, 49 * sizeof(float));
        TfLiteInterpreterInvoke(interpreter);
        TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(output_tensor, output, 49 * sizeof(float));

        printf("Output: \n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 49; j++)
        {
            printf("%02d: %f\n", j, output[j]);
        }
    }

    TfLiteInterpreterDelete(interpreter);
    TfLiteInterpreterOptionsDelete(options);
    TfLiteModelDelete(model);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe some memory corruption. Did you try to run under valgrind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all variable declarations outside and prior to the `for` loop, eg:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

   float input[49] = { 0.0 };
   float output[49] = {0.0};//also needs to be initialized
   //and others...

   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Iteration: %d\n", i);
        ....
```

Do the same for any calls that are creating re-usable objects, or allocating memory.  Re-declaring re-usable objects in a loop (without freeing them before re-declare) can have similar results to calling `malloc` in a loop rather than using `realloc` for subsequent calls.

Your code snippet shows that you have *created* and  *deleted* the following inside the loop:

```
    TfLiteInterpreterDelete(interpreter);
    TfLiteInterpreterOptionsDelete(options);
    TfLiteModelDelete(model);
```

Calling this in a loop may also be problematic.

```
TfLiteTensor* input_tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, 0);
```

`input_tensor`, I believe should be created once, then, in the loop, resized as needed.

From the link you provide:

```
// NOTE: After a resize, the client *must* explicitly allocate tensors before
// attempting to access the resized tensor data or invoke the interpreter.
// REQUIRES: 0 <= input_index < TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensorCount(tensor)
TFL_CAPI_EXPORT extern TfLiteStatus TfLiteInterpreterResizeInputTensor(
    TfLiteInterpreter* interpreter, int32_t input_index, const int* input_dims,
    int32_t input_dims_size);
```

***Edit:***  One other item that seems odd:

```
const TfLiteTensor* output_tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 14);
```

The modifier `const` seems an odd bedfellow to `output_tensor`.  It would seem if this variable will change inside the loop, then it should not be modified to `const`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. My inputs and outputs always have the same size, so I shouldn't need to reallocate memory for them. I have copypasted my modified code into my question. The effect was that it does compile now, however, all the values in the output vector stay at their init values. This would imply that the inference call does not work.

Comment: @DocDriven -  the `const` modifier seems like it might be a problem.  See edit above.

Comment: Thanks, I am more of a Python person, so I am grateful for advice from other people with c background :) In fact, the problem was not the const modifier, but an inconsistency of indexing by the tf team. They just use and upwards-counting indexes in their C API, but for C++ and Python you have to use the indexes provided by the visualize.py script. I will accept your answer here, as the original question regarded the SegFault, not the dumb indexing. Thanks @mpromonet though for giving me the final piece of advice, you both deserve the rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running well if `TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor` use index below `TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensorCount`.

Maybe the tensor index 14 should be 13, but this depends on your model.

Adding some check like :

```
    int count = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensorCount(interpreter);
    printf("output tensor count:%d\n", count);
    if (count > 14) {
       const TfLiteTensor* output_tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 14);

       float output[49];
       TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(output_tensor, output, 49 * sizeof(float));

       printf("Output: \n\n");
       for (int j = 0; j < 49; j++) {
          printf("%d: %f\n", j, output[j]);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I did consider this. I have visualized my model with the visualize.py script and it showed me my inputs have index 0 and the ouputs index 14. But because of the fact that the output vector is untouched by the inference call, I suspect something is wrong with the indexes. Do you know how I can inspect the tensors of the loaded model?

Comment: `TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensorCount(interpreter) - 1` will give you the maximal index to use in  `TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor`

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing piece! The tensor index of the tflite model from visualize.py does NOT equal the index used in here, its just starting at 0 and counting onwards. I do not know why the tensorflow team does not keep this consistent, this is just godawful to deal with.